# "I don't mistake" or "I don't make a mistake" Which one is correct?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, transitive-verbs

I have a query about these sentences:

> If I do not mistake, she would be his fiancée ...

but my teacher told me that it must be expressed in another way

> If I do not make a mistake, she would be his fiancée ...

Why can't I utilize *mistake* as a verb?

Comment: Neither of those sentences is grammatically correct. What is it you are trying to express? The first one might mean "If I'm not mistaken she is his fiancee" or "If I hadn't made a mistake she would be his fiancee."  The would is really throwing me here.

Comment: @DRF  I think the usage is. *upon seeing someone enter that you do not recognise:*. “And who would that be?” “that would be his fiancée [if I’m not mistaken]”

Comment: @jim Yes now you write it like that it seems obvious.:) The two strange sentences next to each other must have confused me. I'll go with that.:)

Comment: Most idiomatic would be "If I am not mistaken, she is his fiancee."

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mistake Sometimes just looking in a dictionary will give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that “If I do not mistake, she would be his fiancée” is ungrammatical.

*Mistake* as a verb is always **transitive** in normal use in current English; that is, you cannot just mistake—you have you mistake *something*. In fact, in the vast majority of cases where you use the verb in regular speech, you are talking about *mistaking something/someone for something/someone else*, which means mistakenly identifying something/someone as something/someone else. For example, “I mistook him for my brother” means that he is not my brother, but when I saw him, I thought for a moment that he was.

So far, your teacher is correct: your sentence is ungrammatical. However, your teacher’s correction is *also* not appropriate. Her version is perhaps not quite ungrammatical, but it does not make very much sense, and the verbal tenses do not match up and make it at least *almost* ungrammatical.

To *make a mistake* means to commit an error, to do something wrong (roughly speaking). It is an act, rather than a statement. If you say something that is incorrect, you make a mistake; if you marry someone whom you do not love, you (presumably) make a big mistake. In your teacher’s sentence, you are saying that she would hypothetically be his fiancée, but only if you do not in the future do something incorrect. That makes very little sense.

What you are in fact trying to say is that you *think* she is his fiancée, but you are not entirely sure. To express this, we generally do not use the verb *to mistake*, nor the noun *a mistake*, but instead the **adjective** *mistaken*, meaning ‘wrong in one’s opinion or belief’. Since there is no link of hypothetical causality between the two statements (she doesn’t magically become his fiancée if your belief is correct), there is no need to use *would be*—a simple present tense suffices:

> If I am not mistaken, she is his fiancée.

There are some cases where *would be* is natural and makes sense, but that requires more context than you have given here (see Jim’s comment to the question). There are also some dialects (especially in Ireland) where they use *would be* a lot more than in most other dialects; but I am guessing you do not live in Ireland, so that’s hardly relevant for you.

Answer (score 0):

'Mistake' as a verb can be both transitve and intransitive; or to say it  other way round, it is the context that makes the verb either.

The problem lies elsewhere. 'If' introduces a condition as a subordinate clause which will be fulfilled in the principal clause ; and the sentence-If I don't mistake......-fails to find that consummation in the principal clause.Hence the mistake.

We can reorganise the sentence like this: If I don't mistake she might have been his fiancee.

The second sentence -If I don't make a mistake- in its attempt to correct that mistake makes use of 'would'(suggesting probability). But this dubiousness is latent in the subodinate clause itself. In that case the principal clause should be just a statement. In the instant case a 'simple present' will do ie.,she is his fiancee.

I think now the  last sentence makes sense grammatically.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that _mistake_ is in common use as an intransitive verb? [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mistake) has a single example from 1895, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mistake#Verb) a single one from 1719, and [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mistake) doesn’t include a transitive definition at all. Even if we do accept the outdated and uncommon intransitive usage of _mistake_, your suggested improvement is actually **worse** than the original: “don’t … might have been” are even more incompatible than “don’t … would be”.